# C# - Print Html instead of string

Tags: c#, html, printing, html-encode

I have a string saved on a database with html tags. I need to print it on my website respecting those styles(like italic, bold).

The problem is instead of a string formatted i get the string with the tags.

I used:

```
<%=System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(dr_stream["Description"].ToString())%>
```

I first tried without html and did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Create a div and assign to the div as `myDiv.innerHtml = yourString`

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out. I was recording the encoded version on the database.
I used Decode instead of Encode and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a solution

ASP.NET MVC

```
@Html.Raw(dr_stream["Description"].ToString())
```

ASP.NET

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" Text='<%#dr_stream["Description"]%>'></asp:Literal>
```